# Powershell error with iex install-module failed

Tags: powershell

I took command from here https://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/13/better-git-with-powershell.aspx/

```
(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1") | iex install-module posh-git
```

but I got this error (I'm running in admin mode)

> Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'posh-git'.
> At line:1 char:78
>
> - ... String("http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1") | iex install-module posh-git
> - ```
>                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make sure what you're downloading before attempting to. Consider the fact that the post is from 2011. The link in the script, psget.net loads one of those generic "buy this domain" pages.

Next, `Invoke-Expression` does not take additional parameters, just the command you were trying to pipe in.

Finally, if you want to install `Posh-Git` - simply run

```
# Requires admin, installs for all users
Install-Module Posh-Git
```

or

```
# Does not require admin and installs for current user
Install-Module Posh-Git -Scope CurrentUser
```